# What can cause the close event to be not be called when exiting an application

Tags: vba, events, ms-access

I've written an application in VBA and it basically starts logging when the form is loaded and stops logging when the form is closed via form_closed event.

It is it then worked out between when the log started and when the log ended how long they were on the application for.

Recently I got told about how their are certain ways the user can close the form without triggering the closed event, e.g. the program crashes?

I'm just here to ask if anyone knows anyway that the user can exit a program without triggering the closed event.

Thanks

Comment: @Santosh already answered your Q, but i want to add other option: event could be triggered, but writing could fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK below reasons may cause to exit application without triggering the event.

1. Accidental PC shutdown
2. User/admin end the process from Task Manager
3. Run-time error occured in code.(As its not compiled code like exe)